# How to Check First Character of a Text in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have texts coming from the database and I try to check text with specific numbers and characters. I need to know how to check a word if the first letter is "1" or not.

How could I do this?

Comment: `text[0] == "1"` will be `True` if the first character is `1`.

Comment: What have you tried coding already?

Comment: Look into [startswith function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith)

Comment: Look up string method `startswith()`

Answer (score 5):

You can access the first letter of the word in the same way as the first item in a list. But remember that the first index is `0`.

```py
if word[0] == "1":
    print("First letter is 1")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `text.startswith("1")` which will return True or False depending on whether your text starts with '1' or not